# Using Serilog for Logging with Azure Table Storage in .NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, .net-core, serilog

Despite hours spent on google, I am not getting there.  We have a Core 3.1 MVC Web App project, and I've been asked to use SeriLog to write logs to Azure Table Storage.  For the life of me, I can't find a working example or tutorial online. Here's what I've done so far:

1. Added the following NuGet's:

- Serilog
- Serilog.Extensions.Logging
- Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage

2. In appsettings.json,I replaced this:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Warning"
    }
```

With this:

```
  "Serilog": {
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "AzureTableStorage",
        "Args": {
          "storageTableName": "Logs",
          "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=***;AccountKey=***;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

And now I am stuck.  This is currently in `Program.cs` in `CreateHostBuilder` :

```
.ConfigureLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddConsole();
})
```

I assume I should replace this? But, with what?  I am not sure where to go from here. The [serilog-sinks-azuretablestorage](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-azuretablestorage) page on Github isn't much help. And I've been unable to find anything via Google that explains how to finish the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I didn't get any bites on this. But after reading about 5 different articles, I managed to figure it out.  In Program.cs, this was there by default:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
        {
            logging.AddConsole();
        })
```

And I replaced it with this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
        {
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                 .ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration)
                 .CreateLogger();

            logging.AddSerilog(logger);
        })
```

`hostingContext` is an instance of `HostBuilderContext` and it contains '.Configuration' which is an instance of `IConfiguration`. So `hostingContext.Configuration` contains all your settings in `appsetting.json`.

In addition to the NuGet packages I mentioned in the OP, I also had to add this one:

> Serilog.Settings.Configuration

(It's amazing how sometimes it can take 7 or 8 hours to write 4 lines of code.)

Answer (score 0):

Add Serilog.Settings.Configuration and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging nuget package to your project it helps to read serilog configuration settings from appsettings.json and ensure you have below Serilog config in your Startup.cs file.

```
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
           //logger config 
            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                                              .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                                              .CreateLogger();

            logger.Information("Logging configured");
            Log.Logger = logger;
        }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            {
                loggingBuilder.AddConfiguration(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
                loggingBuilder.AddConsole();
                loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
                //Add Serilog config to logbuilder
                loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(Log.Logger);
            });
}

//Add this config in appsettings.json
"Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.AzureTableStorage" ],
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "AzureTableStorage",
                "Args": {
                    "storageTableName": "MyAppLogs
                    "connectionString": ""
                }
            }
        ],
        "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
        "Properties": {
            "Application": MyApp
        }
    },
```